# What causes incorrect string filtering in access filter/query?

Tags: sql, ms-access, filter

I have a ODBC linked table in access, each row corresponding to a part number in our company. One of the fields lists the unit of measure for the part. If I filter this field for the string "RL", how is it possible that it returns values other than "RL"?

MTIC_PROD_PUM is currently filtered by "RL" as shown below:
[image: MTIC_PROD_PUM is currently filtered by "RL"]

This table is linked from software we use called DBA. In DBA, the unit of measure for the two part numbers causing the issue were recently changed from "RL" to "EA". It's as if it's filtering by the older value in access.

This is causing issues in queries I've made in access as well.

I'm new to sql, so maybe this is a simple issue? I'm stumped.

[EDIT]

I figured out what the issue what, though I'm not sure what happened. I re-linked ODBC table and the "EA" changed to "RL"

So it was filtering correctly, but not displaying correctly.

From what I understand, ODBC linked tables should always be up-to-date. This value was changed a few days ago and only showed up correctly after relinking the table.

Comment: We'd need to see the SQL code to help. Can you please post it?

Comment: How recently was RL changed to EA? Minutes? Hours? Days? Does this happen every time you run the query? Every time you refresh the filter? If so, it seems like something weird is definitely going on.

Comment: @EvanM I don't believe any sql code is involved here. I am using the built in filter function from access and filtering by "RL." If you save the filter as a query, this is what the sql looks like: 
SELECT *
FROM MTICMSTR
WHERE (((MTICMSTR.MTIC_PROD_PUM)="RL"));